# Pylint and classes that share the same name showing no member error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, pylint

I've have a project that contains multiple AWS Lambdas. Each Lambda has their own Config class which will have different members depending on the Lambda. The issue I'm having is that Pylint is showing "Instance of class has no member" (E1101) error because its picking the Config class from a different Lambda. Is there a way to force it to select the class within its directory?
I'm using VSCode and the structure of my project is as follows:

```
Lambda1 (folder)
 |_ config.py
 |_ lambda_function.py 
Lambda2 (folder)
 |_ config.py
 |_ lambda_function.py
```

Comment: How does the code select the appropriate class? How do you run pylint on the code?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi from config import Config. Pylint runs whenever I do a save

Comment: You say `from config import Config`, but your modules are named `_config`. Since you have an absolute import, I suspect you aren't importing the module you think you are. Try the relative import `from ._config import Config` (assuming this is in `_lambda_function.py`).

Comment: @chepner apologies, the underscore was just to indicate the folder structure, the files are named config.py and lambda_function.py. 


I've tried using relative import but I get the following error.
`Attempted relative import beyond top-level packagePylint(E0402:relative-beyond-top-level)`
I can get rid of the error once I add an empty `__init__.py` file.
The next problem I get is when trying to run a lambda with aws sam, I will now get the following error:
`Unable to import module 'lambda_function': attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: The only way I could get around this last error was to add another folder and updating the handler. so the folder structure is as follows:
`Lambda1 (folder) -> app (folder) -> config.py, lambda_function.py `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using relative import,
so instead of

`from config import Config`

do

`from .config import Config`

I also need to add an empty `__init__.py` file:

```
 Lambda1 (folder)
 |_  __init__.py
 |_  config.py
 |_  lambda_function.py 
Lambda2 (folder)
 |_  __init__.py
 |_  config.py
 |_  lambda_function.py
```

This would get Pylint to detect the correct class.

The next issue was that these changes would cause the lambda to no longer work.

To get the lambda working again I added a folder within each lambda folder like this:

```
 Lambda1 (folder)
 |_  app (folder)
    |_  __init__.py
    |_  config.py
    |_  lambda_function.py 
Lambda2 (folder)
 |_  app (folder)
    |_  __init__.py
    |_  config.py
    |_  lambda_function.py
```

And updated the lambda handler from this:

```
Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
```

to this:

```
Handler: app.lambda_function.lambda_handler
```

I'm not too happy that I need to restructure the files and update the lambda handler, so will continue looking at alternative solutions to avoid this.